# create-react-app created app not linting with npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

According to its [own documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app), a React app generated with `create-react-app` is supposed to include automatic linting when I run `npm start` on my app (created with create-react-app), the linting doesn't happen.

The server starts up and the application functions otherwise. There aren't any error messages, either.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the editor that you use? Is editor is installed with ESLint plugin?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code with the ESLint plugin installed, and VSC appears to be linting okay. It's just `npm start` that doesn't lint.

Comment: Oh ok. I generally see few warnings on the terminal (not complete list) while "npm start"